# get "unrecognized selector sent to class" using singleton

Tags: ios

I am novice in ios and I try to write a simple singleton object to share data between controllers. Here is my code:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "SynthesizeSingleton.h";

@interface BSStore : NSObject

+(BSStore *)sharedStore;

@property (nonatomic,strong) NSArray *sharedNotebooks;

@end



#import "BSStore.h"

@implementation BSStore

SYNTHESIZE_SINGLETON_FOR_CLASS(BSStore)

@synthesize sharedNotebooks;

@end
```

//Write Objects in AppDelegate

```
[BSStore sharedStore].sharedNotebooks = notebooks;
```

//Read objects in a ViewController

```
  Notebook *notebook = [[BSStore sharedStore].sharedNotebooks objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

and I get:

```
2012-10-04 02:01:29.053 BarneyShop[1827:f803] +[BSStore sharedStore]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x69b8
2012-10-04 02:01:29.073 BarneyShop[1827:f803] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[BSStore sharedStore]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x69b8'
*** First throw call stack:
```

Comment: You don't show where you create the singleton.

Comment: SYNTHESIZE_SINGLETON_FOR_CLASS(BSStore)

//
//  SynthesizeSingleton.h
//  CocoaWithLove
//
//  Created by Matt Gallagher on 20/10/08.
//  Copyright 2009 Matt Gallagher. All rights reserved.

Comment: I meant: http://projectswithlove.com/projects/CWLSynthesizeSingleton.h.zip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what your Singleton class should look like:

```
#import "BSStore.h"

@implementation BSStore

@synthesize sharedNotebooks;

+ (BSStore *) sharedStore
{
    static BSStore * singleton;

    if ( ! singleton)
    {
        singleton = [[BSStore alloc] init];

    }
    return singleton;
}

@end
```

Now you can call:

```
[BSStore sharedStore].sharedNotebooks;
```

Comment: Ok. By this way it works. But what is a problem with the my above code using SYNTHESIZE_SINGLETON_FOR_CLASS?

Comment: What above code? Your class is empty, that's whats wrong, your not initializing the class. As far as your comment *SYNTHESIZE_SINGLETON_FOR_CLASS(BSStore) // // SynthesizeSingleton.h // CocoaWithLove // // Created by Matt Gallagher on 20/10/08. // Copyright 2009 Matt Gallagher. All rights reserved.* <-- that is garbage and means nothing in regards to your issue.